# How to know if window.opener comes from my webpage?

Tags: javascript

I have a login popup that modifies its parent page with window.opener.location.href = XXX. The code goes something like this.

```
  if (window.opener) {
      window.opener.location.href = window.location.href;
      self.close();
  }
```

The problem with this, is that if someone has a link to my webpage, like lets say, a link from an email, this code will be executed and the parent is the email client. This will throw a javascript error cause I'm trying to alter a webpage that is not mine.(In Chrome, it says "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL")

I want to know if there is a way I can find out if the window.opener comes from my webpage.

Comment: Why can't you stick that in a `try...catch...` block?

Comment: For some reason in chrome, It doesnt catch it

Comment: you could try checking the domain of the opener. assuming that you're using a single domain. The *real* question is: why are you performing a JS redirect?

Comment: It raises an exception because I'm trying to access information of the other webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not bullet-proof, but can you define some function on your main page and then test for its existence as a check that it is *your* page? Wrapped in a try/catch to avoid other errors when the page isn't yours?

```
// on parent, make this function name something unlikely to appear
// on other pages
function checkParentIdentity() { return "some ID string"; }


// on popup
try {
  if (window.opener
      && window.opener.checkParentIdentity
      && window.opener.checkParentIdentify() === "some ID string") {
     window.opener.location.href = window.location.href;
     self.close();
  }
} catch(e) {
  // error message here
}
```

Having said that, I'm not suggesting it as a *good* idea, just an idea that might fit with your existing code. If it were me I'd move the `location.href` updating into the function on the parent, and then just have the child window call the function to tell the parent to update itself - something you could do with minimal changes to the code I posted. But then if it were me, I'd probably not use a popup at all when I can do a dynamic dialog overlay thingy on the main page (jQuery's dialog is just one easy way to do that).

And having said *that*, why would people have a link directly to your login page? Assuming they might, the point where you want to test whether the right parent window exists is when the login first displays, not after the user enters their details and tries to submit.

Comment: One thing to understand is on every page of my site, I have a dropdown form, like the one in twitter, so you can log in. 

So taking this to account, here are my answers. 1) The location.href can't be in the parent function because it varies according to the page you want to be logged. 2) Its facebook login popup, that's why I dont use Jquery Dialog. 

That being said, the code you supplied, works. Apparently the catch in Chrome does catch the exception,  but still it shows an error in the developer tools. Is there a way for that error to not show?

Comment: Is there no way to do this without the try/catch block? No way to examine window.opener.location to check for validity before attempting to use it? try/catch is pretty expensive...

Comment: @JoeShelby - A single try/catch isn't expensive - it's not like it's in a loop or something. I'd be happy to learn that there's a better way though, if you'd care to suggest it?

Comment: I found that I could instead do a *'key' in window.opener* without a try/catch: @JoeShelby